# How to find matching number in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'me trying to run through the below 'myArr' array and match any numbers with numberID vairable. However I keep getting the else statment displayed in the console when I know there is a match in the array.

Is there a way to run through the array and match any of the numbers?

Also the first number set is the one I'd like to match. I want to display the second number if the first one is matched.

```
<script>
  var numberID = 123456789;

  var myArr = [
    [123456789, 23149232],
    [87649235, 12355678],
    [54353122, 76768621],
    [88907665, 65778448],
  ];

    var ID = numberID;
    var i = myArr.indexOf(ID);
    if(i > -1){
      console.log('We found a match for the following number ID: ' , myArr[0][0]);
      console.log('Here is the matching 2nd number: ' , myArr[0][1]);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Did not find a matching number ID');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you use a "loop".

Comment: Do you to want find all matches, or just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `indexOf` does not search nested arrays, so you will have to check each individual array in `myArr`.

You could use the [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function:

```js
var numberID = 123456789;

var myArr = [
  [123456789, 23149232],
  [87649235, 12355678],
  [54353122, 76768621],
  [88907665, 65778448],
];

var index = myArr.findIndex((array) => array[0] === numberID);
console.log(index);
```

Or if you're just use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function if you want the individual array that begins with `numberID`:

```js
var numberID = 123456789;

var myArr = [
  [123456789, 23149232],
  [87649235, 12355678],
  [54353122, 76768621],
  [88907665, 65778448],
];

var row = myArr.find((array) => array[0] === numberID);
console.log(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.find(elt => elt[0] === 123456789)[1]
```

In English:

```
arr                          // In arr,
  .find(                     // find the 
    elt =>                   // element whose 
      elt[0]                 // first value
        ===                  // is equal to
          123456789          // this magic number
   )                         
[1]                          // and take its second element
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your `myArr` and just check the first index and output the second index on true.

```js
var numberID = 123456789;

var myArr = [
    [123456789, 23149232],
    [87649235, 12355678],
    [54353122, 76768621],
    [88907665, 65778448],
  ];
  
myArr.forEach(val => {
  if (val[0] === numberID) {
    console.log(val[1])
  }
})
```